# Prove that a natural number that consists of $300$ ones, some zeros, and no other digits cannot be a perfect square.

Tags: number-theory

> Prove that a natural number that consists of $300$ ones, some zeros, and no other digits cannot be a perfect square.

I figure I have to evaluate this with mods of some type and suppose the ending of the number could end in $00$ $11$ or $10$,$01$. Then possibly arrive at some contradiction that this is not possible but I'm unsure how to best approach this type of problem.

Comment: The zero are in the end or are they  mixed randomly between the ones?

Comment: Can be anywhere it just a number with $300$ ones and zeroes mixed also.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint**

Answer the following questions:

- Is the number a multiple of $3$?
- Is the number a multiple of $9?$

Comment: Well it is a multiple of $3$ but not by $9$. Could I then conclude from that it can't be a perfect square.

Comment: @HighSchool15 If a square is divisible by a prime, it's divisible by the square of that prime - can you see why?